# React: Merging nested json data with parent data to create multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, jsx

I have an API call to an JSON file which has some events. This events have one title but several showtimes. Is it possible to merge the nested array with the parent object and thus, creating n new events without nested arrays?

**Events**

```
{
    "publication_date": "8.1.2021 4:18",
    "title": "Camerata Salzburg",
    "showtime": [
        {
            "date_start": "2021-02-05",
            "location": "Konzerthaus"
        },
        {
            "location": "Konzerthaus",
            "date_start": "2021-02-07"
        }
    ],
}
```

**How I would like my Events**

```
{
    "publication_date": "8.1.2021 4:18",
    "title": "Camerata Salzburg",
    "date_start": "2021-02-05",
    "location": "Konzerthaus"
},
{
    "publication_date": "8.1.2021 4:18",
    "title": "Camerata Salzburg",
    "location": "Konzerthaus",
    "date_start": "2021-02-07"
}
```

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map` function on the array and create a new array. If your original data is also an array, you can map it first then map the inner array. This will create an array of arrays, but you can fall `flat` on it to merge them into a single array.

```js
const data = [{
  "publication_date": "8.1.2021 4:18",
  "title": "Camerata Salzburg",
  "showtime": [
    {
      "date_start": "2021-02-05",
      "location": "Konzerthaus"
    },
    {
      "location": "Konzerthaus",
      "date_start": "2021-02-07"
    }
  ],
}]

const newData = data.map(title => title.showtime.map(e => ({
  publication_date: title.publication_date,
  title: title.title,
  date_start: e.date_start,
  location: e.location
}))).flat();

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

It's a bit easier to reason about in my opinion, but does require a dependency. So if you're new to javascript, I'd recommend you stick with @Todds solution for now. But maybe something to revisit once you gain a bit more experience and do more data processing.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ publication_date: '8.1.2021 4:18', title: 'Camerata Salzburg', showtime: [ { date_start: '2021-02-05', location: 'Konzerthaus' }, { location: 'Konzerthaus', date_start: '2021-02-07' } ] }];

const flatten = (data) => objectScan(['[*].showtime[*]'], {
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ value, gparent, context }) => {
    const { publication_date, title } = gparent;
    context.push({ publication_date, title, ...value });
  }
})(data, []);

console.log(flatten(myData));
/* => [
 { publication_date: '8.1.2021 4:18', title: 'Camerata Salzburg', date_start: '2021-02-05', location: 'Konzerthaus' },
 { publication_date: '8.1.2021 4:18', title: 'Camerata Salzburg', location: 'Konzerthaus', date_start: '2021-02-07' }
] */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)